# CSS Float - clear both divs with a fixed position

Tags: css

I have a new site I am putting together to learn web coding.

My current code for the section in question is as follows:

```
require_once 'includes/functions.php';    

<?php
    if(logged_in())
    {
        $data = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS num FROM mail WHERE userid = "'.$_SESSION['id'].'"');

        $row = $data->fetch_assoc;

        $mcount = $row['num'];
    }
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo SITENAME; ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
    <?php
    if(logged_in())
    {
        echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '! <a href="mail"><img src="" alt="" width="32" height="32" /> ('.$mcount.')</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Welcome, Guest!';
    }
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="banner"><img src="" alt="" width="1000" height="250" /></div>

    <div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li>
        <?php
        if(logged_in())
        {
        ?>
        <a href="logout">Logout</a>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
        <a href="login">Login/Register</a>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </li>
        <li><a href="forum">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="donate">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

    ... Content to be added here ...

    </div> <!-- end content -->

    <div id="footer">Copyright 2018 <?php echo SITENAME; ?>. All Rights Reserved.<br /><a href="mailto:<?php echo WEBMASTER; ?>">Webmaster</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="tos">Terms of Service</a></div>

    </div> <!-- end wrapper -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

and my CSS for these sections are as such:

```
#navbar
{
    float: left;
}

#navbar ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

#navbar li a
{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover
{
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

#content
{
    float:right;
    width: 810px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My question is this: The Navbar and the Content lines up fine (navbar is fixed to the right so that it will scroll with the page content), but the footer is hidden behind the navbar if the content is shorter than the navbar height.

Is there a way to set the footer min-height to inherit the height of the navbar div so that it will always appear below the fixed navbar instead of behind it?

I researched this on the web, and nothing touched on how to do this specifically (they just said to create a element between the fixed element and the bottom element to create a buffer, which is not what I am trying to do).

### Update

Updated code with the entire php file (index.php)

Website URL for preview to see issue live: [Test Site](http://test.cgcserver.site.nfoservers.com/)

Comment: Could include the markup after the php code get executed,all i can see is the side menu which looks fine

Comment: Please include your markup so we can understand better

Comment: Updated to add full index.php code per request.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the body the height of the browser window by doing the following

```
body
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I had thought about that, but I still need a fix for in the event the end user has their window smaller than the height of the fixed element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going blind on this, Is This the desired look ?

```css
#navbar
{
    float: left;
}

#navbar ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

#navbar li a
{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover
{
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

#content
{
    float:right;
    width: 810px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
    position:  fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li>
    
    <a href="logout">Logout</a>
    
    <a href="login">Login/Register</a>
    
    </li>
    <li><a href="forum">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="donate">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the CSS file like this

```
#content
{
    float:right;
    width: 810px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer
{
    clear:both;
    font-size: 9pt;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I think your expecting answer is this. now the footer is on top of the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a pure CSS without Javascript, you could apply a `min-height` to the `.content` element which will force the `footer` down; In the demo below I have specified the `.content` to have a `min-height: 100vh;` to make sure it is at least 100% of the height of the viewport.

*Read to the comments in the code for reasons for some of my changes*

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /*float: left; Float values do not control the position of fixed elements, the above offset values do*/
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /*position: fixed; Placing your fixed position value on the #navbar element makes more structural sense*/
  overflow: auto;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 810px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh; /*Change this to what you want*/
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 9pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="forum">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="donate">Donate</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>

<div id="footer">
  FOOTER
</div>
```

Another solution would be to set a `margin-bottom` on the `.content` that is the same height as the `#navbar` element:

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  /*float: left; Float values do not control the position of fixed elements, the above offset values do*/
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /*position: fixed; Placing your fixed position value on the #navbar element makes more structural sense*/
  overflow: auto;
}

#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 810px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 136px /*Current height of the #navbar*/; 
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 9pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="forum">Forums</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="donate">Donate</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
</div>

<div id="footer">
  FOOTER
  </div>
```

Comment: Tried the code edits you suggested, which unfortunately did not work the way I was intending.  It did move the navbar out of the way of the footer, but it relocated to the top-left corner of the page (I want it side by side to the content of the page, under the header and banner sections of the site, and above the footer.

I updated the original post with the rest of the code of the page, as well as a link to the test site I am having the issue with if you wish to look it over.  Thanks for the help.